# How should i be storing this data before serializing?

Tags: c#, json

Sorry if my question is a bit bland, Ill try to explain a bit more.

Im currently working on a small application and i want to use JSON to store my data locally as a sort of save/load feature.

Currently my Json looks like this:

```
{
   "asdas": 0.2
}
```

Im using a dictionary to store the items Name and Price and i would like to add more properties. My problem however is i need to loop through my dictionary with integers. So my question is, What should i store my data in before i serialize it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to store JSON locally? Usually it's more of a language to interact between different systems. In any case, a dictionary is pretty much the best thing to serialize to JSON, since it's already a key value pair.

Comment: @SpaceSteak And what if i want a Key and Multiple values?

Comment: Well then it's not already stored in a dictionary... but you can still serialize it to JSON if you want. The way I've done this in the past (although with XML) is a UserSettings object that gets serialized and saved. Worked well. Not sure why one key would have multiple values though.

Answer (score 2):

You should create class with properties representing data you want to store.

```
class MyData
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

and serialize/deserialize it with eg. [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use a [list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) of instances of a [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx).

I don't know what you're storing, but I could imagine it being "Products" with a name and a price. So you create a class "Product" with the [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) "Name" and "Price". You can then store all your "Products" in a list and easily serialize this list into JSON. I can recommend you the [fastJSON library](https://fastjson.codeplex.com/).

Here is a small code sample:

```
public class Product
{
    private string _name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    private float _price = 0.0;
    public float Price
    {
        get
        {
            return _price;
        }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
        }
    }

    public Product(string name, float price)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
```

And here an example console application which produces your JSON (using fastJSON).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a list of products
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        // append, modify, delete list entries
        products.Add(new Product("asdas", 0.2));
        // serialize them and output text to console
        Console.WriteLine(fastJSON.JSON.Instance.ToJSON(products));
    }
}
```

Now you can easily add properties to the Product class.

DISCLAIMER: All code is untested, I don't have a c# compiler here, so take it with a grain of salt. It's merely an example.